# How to add events to overlay tiles in the Google Maps Javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I want to implement a grid overlay to the map, where all tiles should be individually clickable and thus distinguishable from each other, to get the clicked tile boundaries at the end.

I really don't know why the event
`div.onclick = function(){console.log(coord);};` is not fired.

```
function CoordMapType(tileSize){
    this.tileSize = tileSize;
}
CoordMapType.prototype.getTile = function(coord, zoom, ownerDocument){
    var div = ownerDocument.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = coord;
    div.style.width = this.tileSize.width + 'px';
    div.style.height = this.tileSize.height + 'px';
    div.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
    div.style.borderWidth = '1px';
    div.style.borderColor = '#AAAAAA';
    div.onclick = function(){
        console.log(coord);
    };
    return div;
};
```

This method is called during map initialization

```
var map;

function initMap() {
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat:0.0,lng:0.0},
    zoom: 2
});

map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, new CoordMapType(new google.maps.Size(128,128)));
```

The tiles are correctly displayed, but the event is not triggered.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that one can reproduce the issue.

Comment: I updated my question, which now includes the map initialization. I hope this is what you meant.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71133829/724604

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map tiles aren't clickable, the layers over them absorb the click events.  See the description of [MapPanes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapPanes) which indicates which panes receive DOM events.