# How can I have a what3words style effect on my google map tiles?

Tags: google-maps

For reference, what I'm specifically referring to is how they highlight the square border and draw the line out to the tooltip. I didn't really care about the line but found the mouseover behavior interesting.

I also like the hover effect over the various tiles before they're selected.

[Here it is in action](https://what3words.com/)
[image: Light highlight effect]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something I threw together that I'm happy with:

https://jsfiddle.net/0zkyx8g9/14/

```js
    const HOVERED_CLASS_NAME = "tile-hover-hack"

    /*
     * This demo illustrates the coordinate system used to display map tiles in the
     * API.
     *
     * Tiles in Google Maps are numbered from the same origin as that for
     * pixels. For Google's implementation of the Mercator projection, the origin
     * tile is always at the northwest corner of the map, with x values increasing
     * from west to east and y values increasing from north to south.
     *
     * Try panning and zooming the map to see how the coordinates change.
     */
    class CoordMapType {
      tileSize;
      constructor(tileSize) {
        this.tileSize = tileSize;
      }
      getTile(coord, zoom, ownerDocument) {
        const div = ownerDocument.createElement("div");
            div.id = "block_" + coord.x + "_" + coord.y;
        div.innerHTML = String(coord);
        div.style.width = this.tileSize.width + "px";
        div.style.height = this.tileSize.height + "px";
        div.style.fontSize = "0";
        div.style.borderStyle = "solid";
        div.style.borderWidth = "1px";
        div.style.borderColor = "lightgrey";
        div.className = 'tile';
        return div;
      }
      releaseTile(tile) {}
    }

    // must be a factor of 2 (max 256) or swap8 breaks
    const TILE_SIZE = 32; 

    let map;

    function initMap() {
      const chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.85, -87.65);
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: chicago,
        zoom: 3,
      });
      
      // Insert this overlay map type as the first overlay map type at
      // position 0. Note that all overlay map types appear on top of
      // their parent base map.
      map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(
        0,
        new CoordMapType(new google.maps.Size(TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE))
      );
      
      
      // https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-coordinates#maps_map_coordinates-javascript
      map.addListener('mousemove', (event) => {
        const zoom = map.getZoom();
        // console.log('swap 8 on', TILE_SIZE, 'is', swap8(TILE_SIZE));
        const scale = swap8(TILE_SIZE) << zoom;
        const worldCoordinate = project(event.latLng);
        /* console.log('scale:', scale);
        console.log('world:', worldCoordinate.x, worldCoordinate.y); */
        // x = floor ( 5 * 8 ) / 28
        const x = Math.floor((worldCoordinate.x * scale) / TILE_SIZE);
        const y = Math.floor((worldCoordinate.y * scale) / TILE_SIZE);
        const tile = document.getElementById('block_' + x + '_' + y);
    //     console.log(x, y);
        
        // I have the block!
        if (previousTile == null) {
          newTileDetected(tile);
        } else if (previousTile !== tile) {
            newTileDetected(tile);
        }
      });
      

    }


    // do all side-effects relating to new tile
    // 1) de-activate any previous tile styling for active state
    // 2) active tile styling for new tile
    let previousTile;
    const newTileDetected = (tile) => {
        if (tile == null) {
        throw Error("New tile detected was null");
      }
        if (previousTile == null) {
        previousTile = tile;
      } else {
        previousTile.className = "";
      }
      tile.className = HOVERED_CLASS_NAME;
      previousTile = tile;
    }

    function swap8(val) {     
      return ((val & 0x1) << 8) | 
        ((val & 0x2) << 6) | 
        ((val & 0x4) << 4) |    
        ((val & 0x8) << 2) |
        ((val >> 2) & 0x8) |
        ((val >> 4) & 0x4) |
        ((val >> 6) & 0x2) | 
        ((val >> 8) & 0x1); 
    }

    // The mapping between latitude, longitude and pixels is defined by the web
    // mercator projection.
    const project = (latLng) => {
      let siny = Math.sin((latLng.lat() * Math.PI) / 180);

      // Truncating to 0.9999 effectively limits latitude to 89.189. This is
      // about a third of a tile past the edge of the world tile.
      siny = Math.min(Math.max(siny, -0.9999), 0.9999);
      return new google.maps.Point(
        TILE_SIZE * (0.5 + latLng.lng() / 360),
        TILE_SIZE * (0.5 - Math.log((1 + siny) / (1 - siny)) / (4 * Math.PI))
      );
    }
```

```css
    .tile-hover-hack {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
    }
```

This [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-coordinates#maps_map_coordinates-javascript) is what helped a ton for just generally how to handle the mismatch between the information the tiles have available at creation time and the information available in the mouse event.